# .NET 8 , SQL Server Pre-Login Handshake (error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

Tags: .net, docker, openssl, .net-8.0

Our project, which is built on .NET 8, is encountering an issue when trying to connect to our SQL server (version 11.0.5058). The Docker file for our project is as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
Copy . .

RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/MinProtocol = TLSv1.2/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

RUN cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

when I want to open a SQL connection I get this error :

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
```

Connection String:

```
server=(myserver);Database=MyDB;uid=MYUSER;pwd=PASS;TrustServerCertificate=true
```

We’ve tried all the solutions mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/222), but unfortunately, none of them have resolved our problem.

We’re hoping you might be able to assist us in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TrustServerCertificate=true` in the connection string. You can also refer this - [CRUD Operations in ASP.NET Core and SQL Server with Docker](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-aspnet-core-sql-server-crud/) which does the same thing.

Comment: thanks for your answer,  I've also added this but still I get the same error!

Comment: I've added the connection string to the question!

Comment: Are you able to connect to database from SSMS? If yes you can copy the connection string from there and put in in your app and test it once more.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution , the latest comment on [#2242](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2242#issuecomment-1858390282) works for me.

```
RUN sed -i 's/\[openssl_init\]/# [openssl_init]/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf


RUN printf "\n\n[openssl_init]\nssl_conf = ssl_sect" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN printf "\n\n[ssl_sect]\nsystem_default = ssl_default_sect" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN printf "\n\n[ssl_default_sect]\nMinProtocol = TLSv1\nCipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0\n" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: Clearly your SQL Server is still running 2012 and Windows without the latest security updates, otherwise you wouldn't need TLSv1 which is basically broken now. Given you are blindly trusting the certificate, I guess it doesn't matter

Comment: Also you are weakening your security across the board, just to allow an anyway insecure connection to an SQL Server that I hope is not on the public internet.